# scratch org definition file - middle name enable and external sharing

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

I am trying to create a new scratch org definition file that will turn on external sharing and enable middle name.
However i get error messages and the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm) isn't great once you get down into nameSettings

I currrently am using to following settings

```
 "settings":{
    "orgPreferenceSettings":{
        "networksEnabled": true,
        "chatterEnabled": true,
        "enhancedEmailEnabled": true
    },
    "nameSettings":{
        "isMiddleNameEnabled": true
    }
  }
```

However this gives you the following error

> Error  shape/settings/Name.settings  Name  Error parsing file: Element {}isMiddleNameEnabled invalid at this location in type NameSettings

Anyone got a solution to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key for this one is the snippet from the [config file](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm) documentation:

> When converting existing org prefs to settings, the org prefs that start with “Is” have a corresponding setting that starts with “enable”. For example, “IsOrdersEnabled” is “enableOrders” that takes a Boolean value of true or false.

So `IsMiddleNameEnabled` should map to `enableMiddleName`.

The documentation is a little unclear on Scratch Org Settings, in part because they're replacing an older DX nomenclature *as well as* mapping to Metadata API settings.

Comment: That's great! 
thank you